# What does this line mean in Brin/Page's 1998 paper?

Tags: algorithms

In Brin and Page's paper "The Anatomy of a Large-Scale Hypertextual Web Search Engine", they describe the variable "d" in the PageRank algorithm as the probability that a random surfer requests a new random page. On the next line, they state:

> One important variation is to only add the damping factor d to a
>   single page, or a group of pages. This allows for personalization and
>   can make it nearly impossible to deliberately mislead the system in
>   order to get a higher ranking.

What does this mean? Why would they add the damping factor to only a single page?

Does it mean that the random surfer will keep following links until they arrive at a specific page? I don't think this makes sense because the random surfer can get stuck in a loop and never reach that specific page.

Comment: It's probably useful to link the paper [here at 2.1.2](http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/361/1/1998-8.pdf).